# Barcode decoding using Javascript

Tags: barcode-scanner

We are working on an application where barcode image is captured using that device Webcam.

Now we need to show the information (decoded information) in the bar code in a text box. Is there any Javascript API or Plugin to decode the barcode information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QuaggaJS](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/) library supports barcode [streaming from webcam](https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/examples/live_w_locator.html)

Comment: Thanks Tom :). Could you please provide a link or a code snippet where this type of feature is implemented.

Comment: View source on the example page I linked or their github https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS/commit/441534cd8ba2ff15e4231ed41e77b10d5b3cc9ee ?

Comment: I am using this library to read VIN numbers, but it is not reading the barcode properly and when it reads it is a wrong reading.

Answer (score 1):

For browsers that support WebAssembly (85%+ coverage with adoption of iOS 11), you can use this Javascript library that decodes directly from a video feed.

npmjs.com/package/scandit-sdk